# How do I predict volume loss due to evaporation when boiling water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

Suppose I have a pot with diameter $D$ containing a volume of water $V$, being heated by a flame under it. If the ambient air temperature is $T$ and relative humidity is $R$, how can I calculate the expected rate of loss due to evaporation over a period of time, $t$? Assume the period of time begins once the water begins boiling.

**Edit:** For simplicity's sake, also assume the flame is just hot enough to get the water boiling.

Comment: I don't know any formula for this, but wouldn't the heat of the flame and the material of the pot also play a role? A conductive material would heat the water faster and so will a stronger flame.

Comment: Ah, yes, the strength of the flame certainly would, but I'm not sure if the material would matter. If the water is just hot enough to boil and maintain that boil, then whether or not the pot's material conducts heat well shouldn't matter - it's already conducting enough heat.

Comment: Right, but I also said to assume $t$ begins once the water starts boiling. So whether it takes 10 minutes or an hour to get up to the boil, my scenario is concerned only with the volume loss once the boil begins.

Comment: Clausius-Clayperon might help. Just saying.

Comment: The most important thing is the rate of heat input to the boiling water. The air temperature, humidity, and diameter are mostly irrelevant.

Comment: The vaporization enthalpy of liquid water is approximately 2200 kJ/liter, which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know the rate of heat given by the flame to the water.

Suppose the flame transfers $h$ kJ/s to the water. The latent heat of evaporation of water is $2260\ \mathrm{kJ/kg}$.

For energy balance, the heat given to the water must be equal to the amount of heat required to convert water into steam.

$$
h = \dot{m} \times 2260 \\
\therefore \dot{m} = \frac{h}{2260}\ \mathrm{kg/s}
$$

If you say the rate of heat transfer doesn't matter (ignore the flame and assume the water is at a certain temperature and stays at that temperature throughout the experiment),

$$
\dot{m} = \frac{\Theta A (x_\mathrm s - x)}{3600}\ \mathrm{kg/s}
$$

Where
$\Theta = (25 + 19 v)$ is the evaporation coefficient ($\mathrm{kg/(m^2\cdot h)}$). This is an empirical equation, so you can't derive it from first principles.

$v$ is the velocity of air just above the surface of the water ($\mathrm{m/s}$)

$A$ is the surface area of the water ($\mathrm{m^2}$)

$x_\mathrm s$ is the humidity ratio in saturated air at the same temperature as the water surface ($\mathrm{kg}$ $\mathrm{H_2O}$ in $\mathrm{kg}$ dry air)

$x$ is the humidity ratio in the air ($\mathrm{kg}$ $\mathrm{H_2O}$ in $\mathrm{kg}$ dry air)

It's fairly straightforward to find $x$ and $x_\mathrm s$ from the relative humidity and the Mollier chart.

Comment: Since I knew my burner was rated for 22,000 BTU/hr, I went with your first equation.

22,000 BTU/hr = ~6.45kJ/s, and 6.45 kJ/s / 2,260 = ~0.00285kg/s. That came out to roughly 10.274 kg/h (or 2.7gal/hr).

That seemed a little high, but I remember reading somewhere that I could realistically expect ~50% heat loss. That would bring the gal/hr down to 1.35, and looks a lot more reasonable.

Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: Nice! What is BTU and how do you find it? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Pranav (+1) -- but in the top-most formula (h = m x 2260) what do `h` and `m` represent, and what units are they given in?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup `h` is the rate of heat transfer to the water, in kJ/s. `m˙` is the rate at which the water evaporates due to this heat transfer (kg/s)

Comment: Thanks again @PranavHosangadi (+1) While I have you here, if you don't mind, two final followup questions for you if its OK! **(1)** Any chance you can explain how the denominator goes from 2260 to 3600 in your solution above? And **(2)** can you elaborate just a little further on the `Θ=(25+19)` coefficient? What are some typical values for `` for a rolling boil vs violent boil, etc.? I am a homebrewer and trying to use your method to accurately predict how much boiloff I will lose while boiling my beer! Thanks for any help; wonderful answer!

Comment: 1. It goes from 2260 to 3600 because they're unrelated equations. The "if you say..." bit was in response to OP's edit, IIRC. `2260 kJ/kg` is the latent heat of evaporation of water. The `3600` is just converting `/hour` in theta to `/second`2. TBH, I don't remember where I got that equation from, but I'll do some digging over the next couple days and see if I can find the source (which I should have cited in the first place).  @hotmeatballsoup

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup `v` is the velocity of air above the surface, and I don't think it depends significantly on the kind of boiling. It's there to account for increased evaporation when the vapor is moved away by wind. I find the same equation [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/evaporation-water-surface-d_690.html), but I don't think that was my original source.

Comment: I appreciate the digging. I'm a software engineer by trade and homebrewing hobbyist, so I can loosely follow your answer and turn it into a function, and this new info has been really helpful. For `v` I might just null it out for my brew kettle-based boiling purposes (hence `Θ=25`) unless you think there's value to giving `v` a non-zero value (for me). Thanks again!